# What's the English for the Russian saying "Love sometimes plays tricks - you may fall in love with a goat"?

Tags: phrase-requests

In Russian, there is a phrase

> Love sometimes plays tricks - you may fall in love with a goat

(Любовь зла, полюбишь и козла). Goat means a bad person (stupid, abusive).

It is used, when an otherwise intelligent person falls in love with an obviously bad partner (e. g. a smart woman voluntarily stays in relationship with a man, who beats her, or a successful man stays with a woman, who humiliates him).

I'm looking for English equivalents, ideally rhyming.

Comment: I think we should just use your translation of the Russian phrase, it's much more spicy!

Comment: In Norwegian we have a similar phrase *Kjærligheten faller like lett på en lort som på en lilje* which can be loosely translated to *You fall in love with a turd as easily as a lily*. I believe the most similar phrase in English, as others have pointed out, is *Love is blind*. Boring, but expressive.

Comment: There is also a Turkish saying, _Love is a fly that can land either on grass or feces_, which I believe is closer to the Russian one. But I guess as @user122469 as stated, you'll end up with the boring _love is blind_.

Comment: I disagree with your explanation of the original phrase. The person doesn't at all have to be intelligent. The phrase is used among friends, where one complains to another - most often humourously - about their _male_ partner, or when people are gossiping about another couple where a _male_ partner is allegedly somewhat not up to scratch. Also I've never heard it in a way where 'goat' was a reference to a female counterpart. Since 'goat' is masculine it would just sound totally weird.

Comment: @maksimov I know at least two women, who used that phrase in a conversation about a good guy marrying a bad girl (as a concluding remark).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

***[Love is blind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Love+is+blind)***, comes close to what you are referring to :

> - (Cliché)  *If you love someone, you cannot see any faults in that person.*
>
>   - Jill: I don't understand why Joanna likes Tom. He's inconsiderate, he's vain, and he isn't even good-looking. Jane: Love is blind.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary)

Comment: It doesn't carry the exact same nuance, but it's about as close as anything else could get.

Comment: "Love is blind" is much more broad than your Russian saying. There's no requirement that the person be a bad person... it could simply be someone physically unattractive.

Comment: @Catija - it looks like that also the Russian saying refers both to physical and behavioural  characteristics. –

Comment: @Josh61 None of the examples in the OP make that apparent. The OP only states that it's because the person is abusive either physically or mentally, or stupid. I'm not saying it's a bad answer, just qualifying it.

Comment: @Catija the OP is wrong about that. Goat, here, does *not* mean "a bad person". It literally means a literal goat. If you check with Chekhov or Nemirovitch-Danchenko, you will see that the OP here invented that bit. "Goat" *can* have the figurative sense "bad person", and so the saying *can* take on that additional meaning in context, and the OP *can* use it that way. But that's adding a layer of complexity that makes things utterly untranslatable. It's hard enough to translate the actual saying; if we must account for a word play on top of it, we're out of luck.

Comment: (The saying also does not say "love sometimes plays tricks". It says "love is evil". Plain and simple. No tricks, no sometimeses. So the English "love is blind" is actually a surprisingly good fit — same bluntness, same certainty, same grammatical structure.)

Answer (score 7):

Tangentially related is this phrase from *The [Yale] Dictionary of Modern Proverbs* (2012):

> You have to kiss a lot of frogs (toads) to find a prince.

But two offshoots of this saying seem more relevant to the sense of the Russian saying. First, from the title of a book published in 1991 that carries the subtitle "The First Practical Guide to Romantic Love":

> [*Kiss a Frog, You Get Warts*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Kiss_a_Frog_You_Get_Warts.html?id=bnDWliQfcDYC&hl=en)

And second, in one of the subentries to the *Dictionary of Modern Proverbs*:

> 1980 *Good Housekeeping* (Jan.) 196 (cartoon: a young woman wearing a crown speaks from a psychiatrist's couch): "I started out looking for a prince, but now I just like to kiss frogs."

Answer (score 0):

"Opposites attract".  This is used more with Rich/Poor, Smart/Stupid, Good looking/Ugly, thin/fat, tall/short etc. People who are completely opposite personality get attracted to each other.  However this does not cover the abusive (domestic violence/humiliation) component that seems to be indicated by the Russian phrase.

The basis of this phase is the observation that in magnets opposite poles attract and like poles repel.

Comment: Particularly when it's expanded to "Opposites attract divorce lawyers."

Answer (score -2):

We have this saying " Love is in the eye of the beholder"

Comment: Really It's: [***beauty*** is in the eye of the beholder.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beauty_is_in_the_eye_of_the_beholder) But... I suppose you could extend it to *love*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - not a bad expression anyway..https://sailornattie2.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/love-is-in-the-eye-of-the-beholder/

Comment: @Josh61 That link is a blog post is written by a non-native speaker. And there are so many language and spelling errors in it, it's frightening.

Comment: @yes..but I really like *love is in the eye of the beholder*. How could you fall in love with a goat otherwise.